# File does not exits on event Target

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling

I am working on an angular project for the first time which collects data from products. While everything works perfectly file ,i am getting error in the html file of image upload. I am getting this error
**Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.**

This is the html file

```
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="Product Image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product Image:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my .ts file

```
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {
  model:any={}
  fileToUpload: File = null;
  handleFileInput(files:FileList){
  this.fileToUpload=files.item(0);
  console.log(this.fileToUpload);
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('Image', this.fileToUpload);
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload',formData).subscribe((res)=>{
  console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Can someone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't pass the `files` as argument, pass the whole `$event` instead:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="Product Image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Product Image:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
    </div>
</div>

handleFileInput(event){
     this.fileToUpload=event.target.files[0];
     console.log(this.fileToUpload);
     const formData: FormData = new FormData();
     formData.append('Image', this.fileToUpload);
    
 this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload',formData).subscribe((res)=>{
     console.log(res);
  });
```